# Vector with some fixed values as a variable of scipy minimization fucntion

Tags: python, list, scipy, minimize

Is there any way to minimize a function with Scipy whose variable is a list with some specific values that may be 0? I tried to use constraints to solve this problem, but it seems that the minimizer is also iterating over these 0 elements, what leads to more computational expense.

Comment: Could you add some data / code ?

Comment: The code is overcomplicated for such a small problem, so I will sumarize it:
Let's say I want to minimize a function f(w) where w=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. For some reason I need some of the values of w to be 0 during the minimization process. Is there any way to pass this information to scipy oder than with the constraints argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap your function. A very unelegant, simple example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    a, b, c, d = x
    return a**2 + b**2 + c**2 + d**2

def f_with_zeros(z):
    a, d = z
    b = c = 0
    return f([a, b, c, d])

res = minimize(f_with_zeros, [0, 0])
```